# Creating regular vector grid at fine scale and for large area using QGIS

Tags: qgis, resolution, vector-grid

In QGIS 2, we wish to create a regular vector grid with 25*25m resolution and over an area of around 12000 km2. We tried to use:
-vector>research tools> vector grid

- and v.mkgrid function from GRASS via QGIS
  but this was not successful. We tried to create grid with smaller resolution and it did work. So, it seems that the issue is due to the amount of data that this procedure generates.

How do I realize such a fine resolution grid?

Comment: Have you tried a 64 bit build of QGIS? On which Operating System? I have no problem creating a grid on 229000km² with QGIS 1.8.0 32bit using vector grid, lines option; without densifying it to the nodes.

Comment: Andres comment sounds correct. it sounds more like processor speed than qgis

Comment: I am working on W7-64 bits and with QGIS 2.0.

Comment: Try with MMqgis/create/create grid layer

Comment: If the size of the grid file kills your application, try to use a spatial database like Postgis or spatialite to store the data using a spatial index. That way QGIS only has to load the data of the current view, and not the whole file.

Comment: Maybe you can tell us what you're trying to do with the grid, since perhaps there is a better way to get to the outcome you need?